# Vue.js 2.0: Apply vue component rendered using v-html, compile the markup

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, ecmascript-6, vue.js

#### I'm using VueJS 2.0

Is there any way to make the below render as a link?

Here is my vue component:

```
<template>
  <div v-html="markup"></div>
</template>

<script>
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      markup: '<router-link :to="{path: 'https://www.google.com'}"></router-link>',
    });
  },
});
</script>
```

In the above example, I want to dynamically export a piece of markup, it contains some dynamic contents, such as `router-link` like above.

But that content did not compile, and exports a `<router-link>` tag as a final result.

Any way to make it compile programmatically?

#### What I really want is to find a way to compile a piece of html manually. If `v-html` doesn`t work, Is there any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [v-html not rendering vue component in Vue 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261621/v-html-not-rendering-vue-component-in-vue-2)

Comment: @Saurabh Thank you, but I don't want why it cannot, instead I want to get a solution, any ideas?.

Comment: Why do you want to do it, what is your exact problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Saurabh Yes, I just want to dynamically render a list of link, in a more flexable condition. Maybe I want something like this https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/77, in Vue2.0

Answer (score 1):

`v-html` works only for pre-compiled html which is basically generated text.
If you want do dynamically change content, simply use `if` conditions to render your list view based on `prop` that will tell you the type of the list view.

I don't think it's a good idea to save the markup in your db. It's rather more convenient to save some settings in your db and based on those to render the necessary html. (the prop type in your case). Maybe if you provide a more concrete example, some suggestions will follow. As you can see, the answers were based on your `router-link` example which I think is not enough to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to render a list of links, one way to do this can be like this:

```
<template>
  <router-link v-for="list in lists" :to="{path: list}"></router-link>
</template>

<script>
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      lists: ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com']
    });
  },
});
</script>
```

### Edit:

You can use an approach like following as well using with the help of [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dynamicComp: "router-link"
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/2.2.0/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  somethind 
  <component :is="dynamicComp" :to="{path: 'https://www.google.com'}"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know ths, but I want to render a fully dynamic content with any component tag referred.

Comment: @AlfredHuang Can you tell how is your list, can you elaborate more on your list, code and usecase to help understand better, Why I am asking is there can be some other way to do the same thing in vue way.

Comment: I'm developing an admin framework, and working on a `ListView` component, and I may define some field with field type as a `prop` pass to it. And I want to support a field type called `html` to render some dynamic markup, such as `router-link` or `switch` or `image-picker` or `date-picker`, which were declared as Custom Components.

Comment: Master, see this from docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Template-Compilation, What I want is called template compilation here. It seemed I can inject dynamic template using this way. But I don't quite understand how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can instantiate Vue instances via `v-html` directive. You must override the default to do that, which would take lots of efforts.

If you just want dynamic links, why not try this:

```
data: {
  menu: []
}
```

and then :

```
<router-link v-for="item in menu" :to="item.src">{{item.name}}</router-link>
```

PS: Can you give an example that you must do such things? I am really interesting in what needs it would be.

Comment: The simplest way to explain is that I want to change the template dynamically, store the markup fragment in my database

Comment: 大兄弟你咋不直接存数据，然后直接取出来解析成 JavaScript 对象，当Vue的data使用。

Comment: 如果你要硬是存成模板的话，那就从数据库导出给服务器后端生成动态的JavaScript文件吧。