# add Vue component in v-html

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to pass in Vue component, i.e. `<v-icon>person</v-icon>` into an existing component:

```
<MyComponent>
   <div v-html="$store.state.icon" />
</MyComponent>
```

But this does not compile the HTML as a vue component. How would I get this to add the HTML and compile as a vue component?

Comment: Do you get any error while rendering ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [v-html not rendering vue component in Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261621/v-html-not-rendering-vue-component-in-vue-2)

Comment: @ShivamSingh unfortunately it does answer my questions :-)